# Losing Group By columns in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, fillna

In one of the dataframes I fill empty values with average of other values based on group by

Assume my dataframe is like this

```
Month  Dayname  Class  Val1  Val2
Sep    Mon      A      1     2
Sep    Mon      B      3     4
Sep    Tue      A      7     5
Oct    Mon      F      5     2
Oct    Fri      K      2     8
Oct    Fri      F      7     3
Sep    Mon      A      NaN   NaN
Sep    Mon      B      NaN   NaN
Oct    Fri      F      NaN   NaN
```

When I use this code it updates NaNs correctly,

```
df = df.groupby(['Month','Dayname']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

But it removes the group by columns **Month & Dayname**

The end results will be like this

```
  Class  Val1  Val2
  A      1     2
  B      3     4
  A      7     5
  F      5     2
  K      2     8
  F      7     3
  A      2     3
  B      2     3
  F      4.5   5.5
```

How can I do this line with keeping group by columns

Comment: try this: `df = df.groupby(['Month','Dayname']).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())).reset_index(drop=True)` Only difference for me is that it sorts it.

Comment: @LuckyZakary thx, looks like it is working, i will test it further

Comment: Just assign the result to the existing columns.  `df[['Val1', 'Val2']] = df.groupby(['Month','Dayname']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))`

Comment: @MichaelGardner Column names are dynamic, and may change based on the data

Comment: Why do you need to transform versus using an apply function operating on the columns? ```df.groupby([‘Month’,’Day’]).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()), axis=0)```